mysql_upgrade to MariaDB 10.3.39 fails due to missing tables innodb_table_stats and innodb_index_stats
I recently and successfully upgraded MariaDB from version 5.6 to 10.3.39 (RHEL 7 to 8 upgrade). However, on each start of the DB I get this message:
systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3 database server...
mysql-prepare-db-dir[15294]: Database MariaDB is probably initialized in /sdb1/mysql already, nothing is done.
mysql-prepare-db-dir[15294]: If this is not the case, make sure the /sdb1/mysql is empty before running mysql-prepare-db-dir.
mysqld[15336]: 2024-04-18  9:49:42 0 [Warning] 'default-authentication-plugin' is MySQL 5.6 / 5.7 compatible option. To be implemented in later versions.
mysql-check-upgrade[15395]: The datadir located at /sdb1/mysql needs to be upgraded using 'mysql_upgrade' tool. This can be done using the following steps:
mysql-check-upgrade[15395]:   1. Back-up your data before with 'mysql_upgrade'
mysql-check-upgrade[15395]:   2. Start the database daemon using 'service mariadb start'
mysql-check-upgrade[15395]:   3. Run 'mysql_upgrade' with a database user that has sufficient privileges
mysql-check-upgrade[15395]: Read more about 'mysql_upgrade' usage at:
mysql-check-upgrade[15395]: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/sql-commands/table-commands/mysql_upgrade/
systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.3 database server.

Well, those instructions are quite clear, so I followed them. However, the mysql_upgrade call fails like this:
Phase 1/7: Checking and upgrading mysql database
Processing databases
mysql
mysql.column_stats                                 OK
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK

[many more tables "OK"]

Phase 4/7: Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'
ERROR 1813 (HY000) at line 77: Tablespace for table '`mysql`.`innodb_table_stats`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT
ERROR 1813 (HY000) at line 81: Tablespace for table '`mysql`.`innodb_index_stats`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 642: Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 643: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 645: Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 646: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 650: Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 654: Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 657: Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

So there seem to be tablespaces for non-existing tables. ALTER TABLE mysql.innodb_table_stats DISCARD TABLESPACE of course fails because the table is not there. Some web browsing revealed that such tablespaces are in orphaned mysql/*.ibd files. Sure enough, there they are. Let's delete them:
# ls -l mysql/innodb_*
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 65536 Apr 18 10:10 mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 65536 Apr 18 10:10 mysql/innodb_table_stats.ibd
# rm -f mysql/innodb_*
# ls -l mysql/innodb_*
ls: cannot access 'mysql/innodb_*': No such file or directory

So they're gone. However, the next run of mysql_upgrade failed in the same manner, and the .ibd files were there again. This even happens when I stop the server, remove the offending .ibd files, and start it again.
Somehow mysql_update first creates the offending tables (otherwise, where would the .ibd files come from?), then removes them but not the tablespaces (whatever that is), then complains about tablespaces without tables, and then about the missing tables.
Doesn't make sense. How can this be fixed?

I think it's better if you ask this question on Database Administrators Stack Exchange as it fits there more.
